# Changing window URL with drop down?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form name="roomForm">
    <select name="roomMenu"
    onChange="window.location = this.roomForm.roomMenu.options[this.roomForm.roomMenu.selectedIndex].value">
        <option value="">Choose ICU</option>
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="/base/ICU5/example">ICU5</option>
        <option value="/base/ICU6/example">ICU6</option>
        <option value="/base/ICU7/example">ICU7</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Could someone point out why this piece of code is not working? It should redirect to another page when the drop down menu is changed.

Comment: I can get it to open a new window with `onChange="window.open(roomForm.roomMenu.options[roomForm.roomMenu.selectedIndex].value);"` but I want the current page to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has extra ")" and this itself is select box. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZ6ju/)

```
<form name="roomForm">
    <select name="roomMenu"
    onChange="window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="">Choose ICU</option>
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option value="/base/ICU5/example">ICU5</option>
        <option value="/base/ICU6/example">ICU6</option>
        <option value="/base/ICU7/example">ICU7</option>
    </select>
</form>​
```